# Could you just please tell me a word which can be used for a person who can bear a lot before he/she breaks down

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Something like tensile strength (which means the amount of stress a material can bear before breaking). But I want a word which can be used for people. I already know 'strong'.

Comment: What's wrong with *strong*?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the details of the **research you have already done** before asking this question here.

Answer (score 2):

An appropriate word would be **endurance** which is [defined at Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=fortitude&oq=fortitude&aqs=chrome..69i57.4836j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#dobs=endurance) as

> Endurance (noun) 1.the ability to endure an unpleasant or difficult process or situation without giving way.
>
> 2.the capacity of something to last or to withstand wear and tear.

The linked page also gives many synonyms.

However 'endurance' is found used more often in the sense of 'ability to bear physical stress' and the word that describes the ability to bear *mental* stress is

> [**fortitude**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fortitude)
>
> [noun] Strength of mind that allows one to endure pain or adversity with courage.

A related word with a slightly different meaning is **resilience** whose meaning you might like to look up in an online dictionary.

Comment: +1 *Fortitude* it would be; *endurance* works in some cases; not *resilience*, though. Use this link instead: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fortitude

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Kris, which I will edit into the question.